# Angular 2 does not send CORS HTTP AJAX request

Tags: angular, angular2-http

**Angular 2.0.0-rc6**

I am trying to access CouchDB server via CORS AJAX call as below.

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic YWRtaW46TjI4Q29uMy4xYjItNDE=');
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers : headers, withCredentials: true });

this.http.get(this.couchDbUrl, options)
.map(this.extractData)
.catch(this.handleError);
console.log(this.couchDbUrl);
```

There is no `OPTIONS` nor `GET` request emitted from web browser. The `catch` & `map` callback are not fired.  Also there is no error at all!

[image]

If I replace the code with jQuery, it works quite well.

```
jQuery.ajax({
  method  : 'GET',
  url : this.couchDbUrl,
  cache : false,
  crossDomain : true,
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },
  headers : { 'Authorization' : 'Basic YWRtaW46TjI4Q29uMy4xYjItNDE=' }
});
```

[image]

I don't want to involves jQuery, what's the problem with Angular 2 HTTP client?

Comment: Don't show your true login credentials! Everyone can tell from your authorization header that `user=admin` and `pwd=N28Con3.1b2-41`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to `subscribe`.

```
this.http.get(this.couchDbUrl, options)
.map(this.extractData)
.subscribe( data => ...) // Subscribe
.catch(this.handleError);
```

More Info: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html